# Android keyboard next button issue on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am facing an issue, I have username & password fields on activity, now when I click on username keyboard appears but no next button on it and I cannot move to next Edittext control through keyboard in this case,  keyboard displays enter button in it as attached in screenshot which increases its height,

Can anyone guide me what is the solution to this problem (to display next button on edittext)?

[image]

**My Code**

```
txtUserid = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUserID);
        txtUserPasword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);

        txtUserid.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.txtPassword);
        txtUserPasword.setNextFocusDownId(R.id.btnLogin);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

add this lines below your lines of code you provided:

```
txtUserid.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
               (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
          {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                txtUserid.clearFocus();
                txtUserPasword.requestFocus();
                return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
});

txtUserPasword.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
          {
                 // Perform action on Enter key press
                 // check for username - password correctness here
                 return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, it has stopped increasing edittext height but still i have no way to move to next editext :(

Comment: please check my edited answer.Lines in txtUserid's onKeyListener has been changed.

Comment: +1 for smartwork but I don't think this Work for Multiline input?

Comment: @deepakSharma: yes..but i suggested according to his requirement.and obviously it is a trick.

Answer (score 111):

Add    `android:singleLine="true" android:nextFocusDown="@+id/textView2"`  on your xml.
Will show Next key and also focus to the next field.

Comment: This works for me, although it might be important to note that if you set android:imeOptions="actionNext", then it will override the attributes mentioned in this answer

Comment: If you use android:singleLine="true" means, that itself good enough to   visible the "next" button on the keypad

Comment: It works for me when also I get rid of `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`

Answer (score 59):

In your layout, just set the XML attributes `android:imeOptions="actionNext"` for your first three text boxes and `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` for the last one.

[More Examples](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:imeOptions)

Comment: i have used it on edittext but i dont know why it does not work. :(

Answer (score 9):

Another best solution would be:

```
android:singleLine="true" 
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

Comment: "next" produces an error: "Error:(48, 45) String types not allowed (at 'imeOptions' with value 'next').".  It should be "actionNext".  And android:singleLine="true" is deprecated.  Use android:maxLines="1" instead.

Answer (score 7):

If your **EditText** is supposed to have only 1 line, add the attribute `android:singleLine="true"` on your XML, that will remove the Enter key and replace it with *Next* / *Done* button.

Answer (score 5):

add your xml layout ,

in suppose u want 4 edittext in row so first three editext u set below,

```
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

and last one editext u set

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

u add line so add,Use

```
  android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: oddly enough MaxLines="1" didn't work on my Galaxy 4, had to use singleLine="true"

Comment: singleline="true"  its deprecated but its worked bro ,,

Answer (score 4):

You need to take care of few things:

1. Add `android:singleLine="true"`.
2. Add `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/tv2"` on your XML.
3. Don't add `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`, otherwise it will override above two attributes.

Answer (score 2):

use this attribute:

```
android:inputType="textPersonName"
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

android:inputType="text"

line in your edittext tag. and your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just add android:singleLine="true" to the EditText tag in the layout XML..

Comment: It's deprecated. Use `android:maxLines="1"` instead

Answer (score 1):

Just add android:singleLine="true" you don't need that code for that

Answer (score 0):

`android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated

use

```
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:inputType="text"
```

instead