# Keyboard shows nextbutton while i have only one edittext in my xml

Tags: android

Hey friends i am new in android and i am face this problem, i have only one edittext in my xml but when i invoke the keyboard sometimes it show the done button in keyboard and sometime it shows the next button while i have no other edittext in my xml when it shows the done button and i click on that every things works fine and when it shows the next button instead of done and by clicking on that the application is crash because of null pointer exception because it will not get any other edittext in that. here is my xml below

Any help will be appreciated. I have a phone with the android version 4.1.2

`

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconsearch"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edtSearchClubs"
        android:background="@drawable/search_icon" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSearchClubs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Search clubs"
            android:background="@null"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: Please show us the XML code for the button?

Comment: sir this is my xml i was enable to edit my question it return some sort of error with the option of CTRL+K

Comment: @EfrozGhauri you don't even have a button in layout you posted above it only has editText nothing else.....

Comment: I still cant see any XML!

Comment: @EfrozGhauri CTRL+K is for the code you have to paste in that area it's not the error ;)

Comment: may be you have a possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003166/android-keyboard-next-button-issue-on-edittext

Comment: Now you put the xml that is good

Comment: Hasnain your link really help me i found  the solution thanks