# Keyboard next button when using include tag

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have seen/tried the following questions, but mine is not the same:

- [Android keyboard next button issue on EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003166/android-keyboard-next-button-issue-on-edittext)
- [Move to another EditText when Soft Keyboard Next is clicked on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android)

---

First, I have a `CardView` wherein I have a `EditText`, like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/topCard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/myCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        android:clickable="false"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#26c2ef">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardTopTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lessonTitleHeading"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Please provide a name:"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/horiLine"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lessonTitleHeading"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:background="#60000000" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/horiLine"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="Enter name here..."
                android:imeOptions="actionNext" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I then inflate this layout in another by using `include` like this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/lessonTitle"
    layout="@layout/activity_notes_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

and in my Activity class I do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_leason);

    View tvOne = findViewById(R.id.tvOne);
    View tvTwo = findViewById(R.id.tvTwo);
    View tvThree = findViewById(R.id.tvThree);
    View tvFour = findViewById(R.id.tvFour);

    final TextView tvOne = (TextView)vLessonTitle.findViewById(R.id.lessonTitleHeading);
    final EditText etOne = (EditText) vLessonTitle.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    TextView tvTwo = (TextView)vlessonProbStu.findViewById(R.id.lessonTitleHeading);
    final EditText etTwo = (EditText) vlessonProbStu.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    TextView tvThree = (TextView)vLessonWorkedOn.findViewById(R.id.lessonTitleHeading);
    final EditText etThree = (EditText) vLessonWorkedOn.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    TextView tvFour = (TextView)vlessonWhatStudShouldWorkOn.findViewById(R.id.lessonTitleHeading);
    final EditText etFour = (EditText)vlessonWhatStudShouldWorkOn.findViewById(R.id.noteEditText);

    tvOne.setText("This is the first CardView:");
    etOne.setHint("Enter Title Here...");

    tvTwo.setText("This is the second CardView:");
    etTwo.setHint("Enter Text Here...");

    tvThree.setText("This is the third CardView:");
    etThree.setHint("Enter Text Here...");

    tvFour.setText("This is the fourth CardView:");
    etFour.setHint("Enter Text Here...");

    //I tried this, but it didn't work...
    etOne.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                etLessonTitle.clearFocus();
                etLessonProbStu.requestFocus();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

The Layout now looks like this:

[image: FinalLayout]

At this point I have a bunch of `CardView`s with `EditText`s underneath each other like above. I would like to use the next button in the keyboard to go to the next `CardsView`s `EditText`.

If you have a look at my Activity class above, I tried using `setOnKeyListener` and `clearFocus` from the current `EditText` then `requestFocus` on the next `EditText`, but that didn't work.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: try to set **`android:inputType="text"`** to your **`Editext`**

Comment: @NileshRathod LOL, thank you very much, if you answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you need to set **`android:inputType=""`** to your **`Editext`** with **`android:imeOptions="actionNext"`**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horiLine"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:hint="Enter name here..."
    android:inputType="text" // specifies your input type here  
    android:imeOptions="actionNext" />
```

Comment: @ClassA happy to help you enjoy codding

Comment: I have one more question, it you don't mind.. Is it possible to have a return button and a next button, both available?

Comment: yes sure ,but your question i don't get you @ClassA

Comment: Let me rephrase, is it possible to have a enter and a next button shown in the keyboard at the same time?

Comment: i think not @ClassA