# how to enable next option in keyboard in date picker editTextView in android?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have issue in **going next** in edittextView using keyboard.
This edittext is responsible to select calendar date

I searched in the internet for this issue.
Nothing works on me.
Please help me.
Take reference from [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003166/android-keyboard-next-button-issue-on-edittext/9003285#9003285) and worked on it but nothing works.
[image]

Following is the code snippets.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_date_of_birth"
        style="@style/Edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_dob"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/activity_start_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_regular"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_dob"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:textColorHint="#C0C0C0"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/et_password"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"/>
```

Comment: Here you go,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989733/move-to-another-edittext-when-soft-keyboard-next-is-clicked-on-android

Comment: One line answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619352/12811664

Comment: @hafiza did not work  still confused, please help